# Can reporting illegal income be used as incriminating evidence?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, fifth-amendment, self-incrimination

As we all know, in the United States [it is required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_of_illegal_income_in_the_United_States) to report and pay taxes on income obtained illegally. Can the fact that this income is mentioned on a person's tax return be used as evidence that the person committed a crime? If so, how could a criminal comply with the law of reporting his income without relinquishing his right to not self-incriminate?